# QWebView disable text selection on right-click

Tags: qt, webkit, qwebview

Right-clicking on any text on a webpage viewed with `QWebView` on Windows selects the word under the cursor. I want to disable this behaviour, but can't find any reference in the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This preference looks to be deep into **Webkit** (the engine that powers `QWebView` and Google Chrome among many others). There is a [Webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23351) that involves a bit of discussion around the desired behaviour on right-clicking some text, but this discussion (and subsequent changes) occurred *after* **Webkit** was branched to create [QtWebkitRelease20](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKitRelease20) (the version released with **Qt 4.7.x**) - I think this is why the behaviour you want is visible in **Chrome** but not **Qt**. There is another upcoming branch, [QtWebkitRelease22](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKitRelease22), which will be included as part of **Qt 4.8** - I think the change you're after will be implemented in that release.

So your options as I see them are either:

- To bite the bullet and go for [Qt 4.8.0 RC](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/10/13/qt-4-8-0-release-candidate-available/)
- To wait for a stable release of Qt 4.8 and come up with a workaround:

  - Would it work for you to disable the right-click menu completely? [`QWidget::setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) will do the job if so.
  - You could hook up to the [`QWebView::selectionChanged()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebview.html#selectionChanged) `signal` and then use [`findText("")`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebview.html#findText) to force a deselection.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I want to do, that the text did not select when I click on it (right button)

Answer (score 1):

***We can use a JavaScript function to Disable select of Text on Multiple browsers as follow***

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function disableSelection(target){
if (typeof target.onselectstart!="undefined") //For IE 
    target.onselectstart=function(){return false}
else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect!="undefined") //For Firefox
    target.style.MozUserSelect="none"
else //All other route (For Opera)
    target.onmousedown=function(){return false}
target.style.cursor = "default"
}
 </script>
```

***Call to this function***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   disableSelection(document.body)
</script>
```

Comment: This is an Easy solution to Disable text select